# Wordpress contact form plugin that would take a string as an argument

Tags: wordpress

In a page I have a few service package offers. Once "order now" button is clicked under one o the package offers I would like a contact form screen to appear where the exact package would be preselected in a dropdown.

I think a contact form that would take an argument would work well here, but I cannot seem to ind any plugins like this. Does anyone know of any?

Is there any other solution for such situation?

Comment: try to do changes in php file , minor changes are needed

Comment: in what php file? Plugin's? I would rather look for a proper solution that's out there.

Comment: [contact form 7](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) with [dynamic text extension](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/) can take any argument.

Comment: Thanks @ObmerkKronen, worked a charm!

Comment: Added as an answer so the question can be accepted and closed ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use [contact form 7](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) with [dynamic text extension](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/) combo which can take any argument.
It is very useful plugin that can make a form truly dynamic by allowing to set any wanted argument actually, and also some built in ones like post ID, URL, content, etc..